# Checking a R package in RStudio: Error 'file' doesn't exist (working directory does not adapt to project)

Tags: r, devtools, r-package

I want to check a package I have written. When I click on the *Check* button in RStudio, I receive the following message:

```
==> devtools::check(document = FALSE)

Setting env vars --------------------------------------------------------------
CFLAGS  : -Wall -pedantic
CXXFLAGS: -Wall -pedantic
Building BBkUtils -------------------------------------------------------------
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore  \
  --quiet CMD build "U:\Eigene Dateien\R\BBkUtils" --no-resave-data  \
  --no-manual 

* checking for file 'U:\Eigene Dateien\R\BBkUtils/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
* preparing 'BBkUtils':
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* checking for LF line-endings in source and make files
* checking for empty or unneeded directories
* building 'BBkUtils_0.1.0.tar.gz'

Setting env vars --------------------------------------------------------------
_R_CHECK_CRAN_INCOMING_ : FALSE
_R_CHECK_FORCE_SUGGESTS_: FALSE
Checking BBkUtils -------------------------------------------------------------
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore  \
  --quiet CMD check  \
  "C:\Users\s1504gl\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpSyMuXs/BBkUtils_0.1.0.tar.gz"  \
  --as-cran --timings --no-manual 

Warning: 'C:\Users\s1504gl\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpSyMuXs/BBkUtils_0.1.0.tar.gz' is neither a file nor directory, skipping

Error: Check failed: 'U:\Eigene Dateien\R/BBkUtils.Rcheck' doesn't exist
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

This behaviour does not change if I start `devtools::check()` from the R console.

Interestingly, I can build the package without any issues (without checking it before). This also becomes clear from the message above. But for some reason, the package cannot be found in the mentioned temporary folder (which really does not exist as it is stated in the message).

During the checking, the `.tar.gz` file is created one folder level above the project root. Can I somehow tell `devtools::check()` where to look for the `.tar.gz` file?

---

**Edit 1: Problem with working directory**

I figured that the working directory does not adapt to the project. I remains `U:\Eigene Dateien\R` even though it should be `U:\Eigene Dateien\R\BBkUtils`. This happens in all my projects. Any suggestions on that?

---

**Edit 2: How the project was created**

Initially, I created the project using the *New Project Wizard*. Afterwards, I moved the project to another folder. But I do not think, this caused the problem since I observe the same error when I create a new package using the wizard.

I also tried to reset the project root to the correct folder, but the notion *Project root* in the project options remained.

Comment: It is normal that the Rcheck and source packages end up one folder up from the Project root. The problem is more likely caused by your OS. Your output is 100% what I would expect, except for the error that indicates the .tar.gz file can't be found in the temporary directory mentioned there. It might be that R doesn't have writing rights to those temp folders due to some settings there.

Comment: Some questions to check whether I can reproduce: Did you use the New Project wizard to create the package? (probably not, as that would put the wd at the root of the package, not one up). Is your Package Root correctly set in Tools > Project Options > Build Tools ? If it says "Project root", click "Browse" to check whether it's really the correct one. Can you run following code? `mytemp <- tempfile(); writeLines("a",mytemp); readLines(mytemp)`

Comment: I updated the question to include some answers to your questions. I will give you the results on the code you posted on monday, when I will be back in my office.

Comment: Can you also add the versions of R, RStudio and devtools? I tried to reproduce your error, but I can't. The project root is always the directory where the .Rproj is stored. If that one is stored in U:\Eigene Dateien\R , the behaviour is normal. If it is not, I frankly have no clue what you did to get at this point...

Comment: I use RStudio 1.0.44 with R 3.3.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the information from my colleage that there was a function `.First` in the file `C:\Program Files\R\etc\Rprofile.site` which was setting the working directory to `U:\Eigene Dateien\R`.

Removing the corresponding line and restarting R fixed my problem.